# How do I take string input from a keyboard and store it in a list?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I need to build a small madlib program that will use a "for" loop to ask for 3 separate parts of speech(enter an adjective, enter a noun, and enter another noun), I need to it ask for the info at 3 separate times as in enter a noun is requested and the user types something in then hits return which would cause it to request the second noun and so on and so forth. I need all 3 of the inputs stored in a list. i realize this is a pretty basic question, but i am new to python and programming in general, I'm just trying to keep up with a fast paced class that i am taking and the help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
values = []

for question in ['Question 1 ', 'Question 2 ', 'Question 3 ']:
    values.append(raw_input(question))

print values
```

Output

```
Question 1 Okay
Question 2 Not ok
Question 3 Actually ok
['Okay', 'Not ok', 'Actually ok']
```

Comment: +1 answered to the point, too bad the question of this new user is closed, (this site sucks as it becomes more popular)